# Removing the dashed border on a select field in FireFox without causing the text to go black when the select field has a dark background

Tags: css

If you look at the fiddle here, the goal is to make the 2nd select element not have the border like the 3rd select element when choosing an item (like the 1st select element), but without having the text go invisible.

```css
#test1, #test3 {
  background: #fff;
}
#test2 {
  background: #000;
}

#test1 select, #test3 select {
  color: #000;
}

#test2 select {
  color: #fff;
}

#test1 select:-moz-focusring, #test2 select:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 0;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}

select {
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">
  <select>
    <option>blah</option>
    <option>blah2</option>
    <option>blah3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="test2">
  <select>
    <option>blah</option>
    <option>blah2</option>
    <option>blah3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="test3">
  <select>
    <option>blah</option>
    <option>blah2</option>
    <option>blah3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Will the person who is trying to close this please explain why? The question is clear, the code producing the error is in the question body, etc.

Comment: @MrLister I read it 3 times and not able to understand and nothing special is happening on FF for me (didn't vote to close btw)

Comment: There is a dashed border around the 3rd select item after selecting. The known fix is applied to select 1 and 2, but the font goes missing after selecting select 2 with the fix applied.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The problem is that in Firefox, the second select element is black text on black background when focused - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWvZW.jpg) - and if you change the color, the dotted outline becomes visible (in the foreground color). The OP's attempts to hide the dotted outline all failed, and so did mine.

Comment: @MrLister its seems a bug related to version or OS because I don't this.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good one. Linux, KDE, Firefox 52.9.0 ESR here. Eskimo, what is your system?

Comment: @MrLister Firefox 62.0.3 (64 bits) Quatum ,Windows 8.1

Comment: I'm on macOS Mojave, issue happens on stable and dev FF